# Whats the difference between a circuit with a capacitor under DC and a RC circuit under DC?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, dc

Does the process of "charging" and "discharging" occur in the same way but with more resistance ?
Im not too sure on what the difference is between the two and whether they behave differently.

Comment: There ism always a resistor no matter how much you think there isn't so, A = B.

Comment: What do you mean by "a circuit with a capacitor"? Just any circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor in RC circuit will be charged slower due to lower current flowing to the capacitor.
You can read about RC circuit in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit).

Answer (score 0):

Any real circuit has capacitance, resistance, and inductance.  These are usually relatively large when dealing with lumped elements, but they exist in wires, traces, connections, etc.  So yes, IRL it's the same with and without the resistor, but the value of the resistive element is much smaller.